# How to count the data size by key range by using IDBIndex.count()?

Tags: indexeddb

I was checking the MDN docs about IDBIndex.count(), which says

```
var request = myIndex.count(key);
The key or key range that identifies the record to be counted.
```

What is the form of `key` in this case? Say I want to count the data which has the key `date` and the range is from `20160101` to `20160105`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IdbkeyRange. Here is the link for doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange/bound

So in your case the solution will be -

```
var key = IDBKeyRange.bound(20160101, 20160105);
var request = myIndex.count(key);
reques.onsuccess = function(){
    var count = request.result;
}
```

Hope this helps you to understand. Although i would suggest you to use some library like jsstore, dexie, couchdb etc. This will solve your problem as indexeddb is very complex and sometimes its kinda of tough to get something real.